# Modify fields in extraneous function

Tags: c#, function, class

I have a lot of duplicate code places:

```
if (claimSettingHistoryDto.NewClaimTypeName == claimSettingHistoryDto.OldClaimTypeName)
{
    claimSettingHistoryDto.NewClaimTypeName = null;
    claimSettingHistoryDto.OldClaimTypeName = null;
}

if (claimSettingHistoryDto.NewApplicantName == claimSettingHistoryDto.OldApplicantName)
{
    claimSettingHistoryDto.NewApplicantName = null;
    claimSettingHistoryDto.OldApplicantName = null;
}

if (claimSettingHistoryDto.NewDamageSparePartsTotalCostInsertion == claimSettingHistoryDto.OldDamageSparePartsTotalCostInsertion)
{
    claimSettingHistoryDto.NewDamageSparePartsTotalCostInsertion = null;
    claimSettingHistoryDto.OldDamageSparePartsTotalCostInsertion = null;
}
```

and so constantly for different classes of different fields

I wish I had a feature like this:

```
private void SetNull(object newData, object oldData)
{
   if (newData == oldData)
   {
newData = null;
      oldData = null;
   }
}
```

but of course I understand that this is not true, since I only change the local value inside the function. How do I change the class field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing that, with varying positions on the "good idea" to "bad idea" spectrum.

### Fields as `ref` parameters (good idea)

> (...) this is not true, since I only change the local value inside the function

You're wrong, because `ref` and `out` parameters allow you to change values non-locally.

If you have access to the actual fields, you can pass them as a `ref` parameter:

```cs
public class Dto
{
    private string? _old;
    private string? _new;
    
    public string? Old => _old;
    
    public string? New => _new;
    
    public void Foo() {
        SetNullIfEqual(ref _new, ref _old);
    }
    
    private static void SetNullIfEqual<T>(ref T? newData, ref T? oldData) where T: class
    {
       if (newData == oldData)
       {
          newData = null;
          oldData = null;
       }
    }
}
```

More info on passing as reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference).

This won't work with properties, even if they have a default setter. Properties are not fields, they're methods in disguise. If you can't access the actual fields...

### Properties as delegates (meh idea)

... having access to properties only you'd need to pass them as delegates like this:

```cs
public class Dto
{
    public string? Old { get; set; } 
    public string? New { get; set; }
}

public class Outside
{
    public void Foo(Dto dto) {
        SetNullIfEqual(() => dto.New, () => dto.Old, v => dto.New = v, v => dto.Old = v);
    }
    private static void SetNullIfEqual<T>(
        Func<T?> getNew,
        Func<T?> getOld,
        Action<T?> setNew,
        Action<T?> setOld) where T: class
    {
        if (getNew() == getOld())
        {
            setNew(null);
            setOld(null);
        }
    }
}
```

This is clunky though, you have to question how much space it'd actually save. An instance method working on fields as in the first suggestion works much better.

### When you have reflection everything looks like a nail (probably bad idea)

You can also do this with reflection, which will remove all safety, give much worse performance, but the absolute most flexibility.

```cs
using System.Reflection;

public class Dto
{
    public string? Old { get; set; } 
    public string? New { get; set; }
}

public class Outside
{
    public void Foo(Dto dto) {
        SetNullIfEqual(nameof(dto.New), nameof(dto.Old), dto);
    }
    
    private static void SetNullIfEqual<T>(
        string newPropName,
        string oldPropName,
        T instance)
    {
        PropertyInfo newProp = typeof(T).GetProperty(newPropName);
        PropertyInfo oldProp = typeof(T).GetProperty(oldPropName);
        
        if (Equals(newProp.GetValue(instance), oldProp.GetValue(instance)))
        {
            newProp.SetValue(instance, null);
            oldProp.SetValue(instance, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I removed all error handling for brevity.

### Recommendation

I'd go with the fields-as-`ref`-parameters way. If the method in question lives outside of the type, so it can't have access to the fields (don't ever use `public` fields please), I'd just move it into the type. In your case it'd be a bunch of methods called `SetClaimTypeName`, `SetApplicantName`, etc.